# How do I hide the status bar in my Android 11 app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11, android-statusbar, android-api-levels

Every method I came across to hide status bar of my Android app is deprecated in Android 11.

Does anyone know about any current acceptable method?

Also I use Kotlin to develop my apps.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When your device is API-30 (Android 11; minSdkVersion 30) or later , `setSystemUiVisibility` is deprecated and you can use the newly introduced `WindowInsetsController` instead. (And note that you cannot use `WindowInsetsController` on API-29 or earlier).

So the official reference says:

> This method was deprecated in API level 30.
> SystemUiVisibility flags are deprecated. Use `WindowInsetsController` instead.

You should use [`WindowInsetsController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsController) class.

in Kotlin:

```kotlin
window.decorView.windowInsetsController!!.hide(
    android.view.WindowInsets.Type.statusBars()
)
```

in Java:

```java
getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowInsetsController().hide(
    android.view.WindowInsets.Type.statusBars()
);
```

If you also want to hide NavigationBar:

in Kotlin:

```kotlin
window.decorView.windowInsetsController!!.hide(
    android.view.WindowInsets.Type.statusBars()
            or android.view.WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()
)
```

in Java:

```java
getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowInsetsController().hide(
    android.view.WindowInsets.Type.statusBars()
            | android.view.WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()
);
```

Comment: I tried to hide the status bar and this error showed up (My API is 21)   ->                                                                                       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getWindowInsetsController()Landroid/view/WindowInsetsController; in class Landroid/view/View; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.view.View' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
        at com.example.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:11)

Comment: @RudraRaina If your app is API-21, `setSystemUiVisibility` is not deprecated and you can use it only. While, only when you use minSdkVersion 30 or later, `setSystemUiVisibility` is deprecated and you can use `windowInsetsController`.

Answer (score 9):

**API LEVEL < 16**

If you want to hide the `status bar` in your application you can simply do this by making your app FULLSCREEN. Inside your `onCreate` method just add `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
```

This is if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16`.

**API LEVEL >= 16 AND < 30**

This is for `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` greater than 16;

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Just add this inside your `onCreate` where you want to hide the `status bar`. More you can read here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status#41

---

**EDIT: API LEVEL >= 30**

It seems that `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` is also depricated from Android 11 even if it didn't say anything in the documentation. But based on [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/modifying-system-ui-visibility-in-android-11-e66a4128898b) you can do this in Android 11 you need to use [WindowInsetsController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsController) and its [hide()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsController#hide(int)) method. Like the other answer suggested you can use:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowInsetsController().hide(
        android.view.WindowInsets.Type.statusBars()
    );
```

So, this is for Android 11 and later, other methods are for earlier versions.

Comment: SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN & SystemUiVisibility are deprecated sir . Although it works but is there any code which is not deprecated ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't see that because it didn't say anything in the documentation I read, you can check the link above. My bad.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://medium.com/swlh/modifying-system-ui-visibility-in-android-11-e66a4128898b

Comment: @SlothCoding [List of deprecated stuffs](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/30/changes/android.view.View)

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way to hide/show status bar in kotlin.

```
private fun Activity.hideStatusBars() {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView)
        .hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
}

private fun Activity.showStatusBars() {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView)
        .hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
}
```

If you need to show/hide both status & navigation bar use `systemBars()` instead of `statusBars()` as following example.

```
private fun Activity.hideSystemBars() {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView)
        .hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
}

private fun Activity.showSystemBars() {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView)
        .hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. If SDK is equal to or greater than 30,

```
private void hideSystemBars() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    WindowInsetsController windowInsetsController = decorView.getWindowInsetsController();
    if (windowInsetsController == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
    windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(
            WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    );
    // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
    windowInsetsController.hide(android.view.WindowInsets.Type.systemBars());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this?

```
// Enables regular immersive mode.
// For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
// Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

[Enable fullscreen mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#kotlin) [Hide the status bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status)

Comment: These is the deprecated method asked to avoid.