# Hide status bar in Android 10 (API 29) and use its space in the application

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I am trying to hide status bar in Android 10. I've already read a lot of answers to similar questions, but they don't work for my device. The goal is to use the space of the status bar as a part of application view:

[image]

Some of the solutions described below work on emulator, but don't work on my physical device (Redmi Note 10, API version 29).

I would appreciate any advice.

###### What I have tried:

- Using different predefined styles like `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` and so on.
- Using different style attributes including: `android:windowFullscreen`, `fitsSystemWindows` etc.
- Setting different styles in program code using **setSystemUiVisibility** including `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN`, `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY`, `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`, `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN`, `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION`, `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE`.
- Adding and removing different flags using **clearFlags**, **addFlags** and **setFlags**.
- Setting status bar color to transparent using **setStatusBarColor**.
- Requesting different features using **requestWindowFeature**.
- Changing layout top padding to negative values.
- Using insets by defining **applyTopWindowInsetsForView** and **onApplyWindowInsets** functions.

###### What I've managed to do.

I've managed to get two results, but neither of them is good for me.

1. Translucent status bar.

[image]

2. Completely black status bar without taking its space for app view.

[image]

###### UPDATE 10 May 2022:

According to the following answer it is impossible to use `WindowInsetsController` on API 29 or earlier: [How do I hide the status bar in my Android 11 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66075399/how-do-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-my-android-11-app)

##### SOLUTION 1

Proposed by [@Zain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9851608/zain).

Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsCompat = new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());
    windowInsetsCompat.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars());        
    windowInsetsCompat.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
    ...
```

theme.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

##### SOLUTION 2

Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...        
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
    );        
    ...
```

theme.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to display contents content edge-to-edge in your app ([Documentation reference)](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge)

**Step 1:** Use: `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`

> This is the primary step for ensuring that your app goes edge-to-edge, that is, laid out using the entire width and height of the display. Use WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false) to lay out your app behind the system bars, as shown in the following code example:

**Step 2:** Hide the status bar using `WindowInsetsControllerCompat`:

```
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).apply {
        // Hide the status bar
        hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
        // Allow showing the status bar with swiping from top to bottom
        systemBarsBehavior =
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    }
```

**Step 3:** As from step 1 the activity contents at the bottom will be obscured by the bottom navigation bar; then you need to adjust the bottom margin of the root layout of the activity to height of the navigation bar by using `WindowInsetsListener`:

Kotlin:

```
// root layout of your activity
val root = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root)
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(
    root
) { view: View, windowInsets: WindowInsetsCompat ->
    val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    view.layoutParams = (view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
        // draw on top of the bottom navigation bar
        bottomMargin = insets.bottom
    }

    // Return CONSUMED if you don't want the window insets to keep being
    // passed down to descendant views.
    WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
}
```

Java:

```
WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsCompat = new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());

windowInsetsCompat.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars());
windowInsetsCompat.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);

// root layout of your activity
ConstraintLayout root = findViewById(R.id.root);

ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(
        root
        , (view, windowInsets) -> {
            Insets insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            params.bottomMargin = insets.bottom;
            return WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED;
        });
```

**Step 4:** Finally make sure that drawing in cutout area is allowed in your app's theme:

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">always</item>
```

Comment: I tried to adopt your solution to Java and my minSdk=26 using the documentation reference you provided. But the following code gives null: `WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =                ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getWindow().getDecorView());`

Comment: Clarification: `windowInsetsController` equals zero only on my physical device. On emularor it is a valid `WindowInsetsControllerCompat`.

Comment: I replaced `WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getWindow().getDecorView());` with `WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());` and `windowInsetsController` started to be filled. But if `windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());` is called, then I get completely black status bar (which is wrong).

Comment: My device SDK version is 29. And according to this answer it is impossible to use `WindowInsetsController` on API-29 or earlier): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66075399/how-do-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-my-android-11-app

Comment: @IvanBychkov I just added the java equivalent can you test that now.

Comment: Thank you. This code works if `always` is changed to `shortEdges` (`always` is incorrect value). Also, `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` appears to be not required (it works without this code).

Comment: My content gets behind the camera of mobiles, I want to give proper padding equivalent to statusbar.. e.g. statusBar.visibility = invisible (not gone)

Comment: @SohaibAhmed You'd use `<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">never</item>` to do that

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The following line was necessary:

`<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>`